# Community ads broken?

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising

I noticed a blank ad, and clicked on the Stats link to see this:

[image: Community Promotions Ads page Nov 17, 2016, 4:31 PM EST, showing several blank ads]

Something seems broken. I note that the Community Promotion Ads meta question is fine, all the images are there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Argh. This issue popped on a few other sites as well but it's difficult to spot every instance. We're rolling out a fix to clean this up.

Thank you for bringing this to our attention!

::high five::